# Why does the filtering by notnull() not work?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `cMean`. Its origin is some resampling of some data. It contains many NaN values and I wanted to get rid of them so I tried `cMean[cMean.notnull()]`. However, they still show up:
[image]

Can you explain what is going on here? It seems `cMean.notnull()` works correct, as you can see here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work as `cMean.notnull()` gives you a 2D output, and you need a 1D Series to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Use the specific column of interest:

```
out = cMean[cMean['population'].notnull()]
```

Or aggregate with `any`/`all` if you want to consider several columns:

```
out = cMean[cMean.notnull().any(axis=1)]
```

Note that you can also use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
out = cMean.dropna(subset=['population'])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you explain what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: I updated the answer, using `cMean.notnull()` gives a 2D output, you need 1D to slice ;)